# Weird black artifacts when launching programs

Tags: kubuntu, kde, visual-artifacts

Sometimes when I open a new window/launch a program I get these weird black boxes appearing on the screen. Here is some info about my system (I customised Ubuntu based on a post I saw on r/unixporn):

- OS: Ubuntu 19.10
- DE: KDE (Plasma)
- WM: KWin
- WM Theme: hello
- Theme: Arc Dark[KDE], Breeze[GTK2/3]
- I also use latte dock.

A screenshot of this happening:

[image: black box on left half of screen]

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you install `inxi` and run `inxi -SGxxz` in a Kubuntu session, [edit] your question to include that output (as text by copy/paste). • Does this happen if you log into a Ubuntu session? • If you log into a Kubuntu session and turn off compositing (`Shift+Alt+F12` is the toggle for that) does it still happen?